# Como incluir um arquivo de outro diretório no index.php

Tags: php

Tenho em minha pasta raiz o meu *index.php*. Também tenho, em minha pasta raiz, outra pasta chamada *componentes*.

Dentro da pasta *componentes*, tenho um arquivo chamado *menu.php*, contendo os códigos do menu do site.

Quero incluir o arquivo menu no meu index. Quando faço isto — utilizando o código abaixo — ele abre, mas com os links errados.

```
<?php include "componentes/menu.php";?>
```

Por Exemplo:

No *menu.php* está

```
<ul>
   <a href="../index.php"> <li>home<li> </a>
<ul>
```

O *link* acima vai abrir normalmente, mas se eu "puxar" o arquivo *menu.php* noutro diretório, vai dar erro por causa do `../index.php`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Amigo, primeiramente para isto, você deve usar JavaScript... Siga o exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <!-- importe a biblioteca jquery para usar o código javascript-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="menu"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#menu").load("componentes/menu.html");
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo menu.html na pasta componentes:

```
<ul>
    <a href="./pagina.php"><li>Teste</li></a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Vlw vou pesquisar um pouco sobre isso, tamo junto!

Comment: Por nada amigo ><

Comment: consequi fazer, mais o problema do link continua! se eu criar uma outra pasta na raiz e criar um arquivo nala e puxar o menu.php, vai dar erro no link

Comment: no menu inicio eu coloquei <a href="./index.php"> quando puxei no index.php foi perfeitamente! mais se eu criar uma outra pasta na raiz, e criar um arquivo nala, e puxar o menu.php o diretório do menu muda em relação a essa nova pasta!

Comment: Amigo, está desse jeito por causa que o menu deve ser puxado apenas nos arquivos da raiz do site. A não ser que você deixe o arquivo do menu dentro da raiz principal em vez da pasta componentes. Experimente isso

Comment: entendí! desse que está nao tem como fazer! vou deixar o menu junto ao index obrigado por tudo! S2